# Index Name in Kibana can be different or should be same as inddex created by logstash when it supply the data to elastic search?

Tags: indexing, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am using ELK stack in my organization. i wanted to understand the pipeline across ELK stack along with filebeat.
I could see the index name called (let s take it as XYZ) present in my kibana UI through console command "GET _all".
I wanted to know if the index name i.e 'XYZ' was provided by logstash to elasticsearch? or is it could be different name?

Answer (score 0):

Index name used in outputs.elasticsearch of logstash can be different to the actual index name you see in kibana monitoring or the _cat/indices API call when you use index aliases.

An example is when you use Index Lifecycle management to rollover and retire older indices. For this to work, you’d need to create an index alias say xyz, an ilm policy to define rollover parameters like size etc and finally an index template that maps this index alias and Ilm policy to an index pattern. Here, you’d specify the index name in logstash to be xyz but the actual index names in elasticsearch would be something like xyz-00000, xyz-00001 etc.

More on aliases here [Elasticsearch Aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/aliases.html)

Comment: Hey Harish, I dont see an alias name for the xyz(or the only index) in kibana. i.e through GET _All.  but the index pattern is defaulted as  xyz* . so, can i say that in the outputs.elasticsearch of logstash file it would have had " index = > "xyz*" ?

Comment: @user9460356 in the output section you’d see the index name as is - without any wildcards. The index pattern in kibana is a pattern hence the wildcard. The idea is for kibana to search across indices and provide the user a single pane to search without having to worry about knowing the exact index names. Having said that you have a way to create an index pattern that is an exact match of the index name, if that is what you’re after.

Comment: Understood ,@harishkb. thank you for the detailing.

Comment: @user9460356 Np :) please upvote the answer if you found it useful :)